# list of column labels as variable to keyword

Tags: pandas

I am using Pandas dataframes to perform operations on tables of data.  Four types of output csv files need to be written depending on values in columns.  I can make a list of the column headers I want written to csv but can't pass the list to df.to_csv('filename.csv', columns=['fixed1', 'fixed2', variable_list]).  I don't want to write out all of the column headers for all conditions.  I have columns with intermediate calculations so I don't want to write all columns to csv.

I tried creating a list of the headers and passing a subset to df.to_csv but it fails.

```
headers = list(df_subset.columns.values)
variable_list = [header for header in headers if header.startswith('foo:')]
print variable_list
df_subset.to_csv('filename.csv', mode= 'w', columns=['fixed1','fixed2', variable_list)
```

For once condition, I expect a csv output with columns fixed1, fixed2, foo:1, foo:2, for another condition I expect a csv with columns fixed1, fixed2, foo:3, foo:4, foo:5

The print statement gives the subset list but the df method fails.

`````
['foo:1','foo:2']

File "multifas_trim.py", line 332, in main
    index=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1744, in to_csv
    escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.obj = self.obj.loc[:, cols]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1472, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 875, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 226, in _has_valid_tuple
    .format(types=self._valid_types))
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [labels (MUST BE IN THE INDEX), slices of labels (BOTH endpoints included! Can be slices of integers if the index is integers), listlike of labels, boolean] types````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a nested `['fixed1', 'fixed2', ['foo:1', 'foo:2']]` where want you want is a flat list. That is, you'll want to do

```
columns=['fixed1', 'fixed2'] + variable_list
```